# How to export multiple months into RDBMS from Essbase and not have it stored as separate columns

Tags: oracle, rdbms, cube, essbase

I'm currently working on a script to export a BSO essbase cube into a RDBMS and running into issues with the export. Whenever I select May and Jun together it comes in as 2 different columns instead of just 1 column called ESS_PERIOD.

Does anyone know how to have the month field (ESS_PERIOD) come in as 1 column?
**Script is below

```
SET LOCKBLOCK HIGH;
SET UPDATECALC OFF;
SET CALCPARALLEL 3;
SET FRMLBOTTOMUP ON;
SET CALCTASKDIMS 2;
SET CACHE HIGH;


SET DATAEXPORTOPTIONS 
{ 
DataExportLevel LEVEL0;
/*DataExportDimHeader ON;*/
DATAEXPORTCOLFORMAT ON;
DATAEXPORTDECIMAL 2;
DataExportOverwriteFile ON;
DataExportDryRun OFF;
DataExportDynamicCalc OFF;
};


FIX (
        /*@Relative("Direct Margin", 0),*/
       /*"Direct Margin",*/
    @Relative("Custom4", 0),
         @Relative("Territory",0),
        @Relative ("Entity",0), 
        @Relative("ProductFamily",0), 
        @Relative ("RETL",0),
         "No_CC",
        @Relative ("customer", 0),
         "FY17",
         "Actual",  
         "USD",
       "May" ,
       "Jun"
)

                    DATAEXPORT "DSN" "DB" "TABLE" "USERID" "PW";

ENDFIX
```

Comment: I didn't think the export options were case sensitive, but if you are getting more than column for the time period, it would seem like the data export column format option is not being honored. Have you tried with the proper casing "DataExportColFormat" instead of all caps?

Comment: Just tried proper casing DataExportColFormat...still importing as 2 different columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataexport always put one of dense dimension to column  
 
 you need to create fake dimension with one member - put it on the dense place and use it column set definition in dataexport set command